# CF pushing - the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, apache, maven, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am using cf for the first time, trying to deploy a simple app to Bluemix. When I try cf push, I get this error:

```
E:\Program Files\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.41\webapps\helloServletMaven\target
λ cf push /helloServletMaven -p /helloServletMaven.war
Creating app /helloServletMaven in org alexander.kirwan / space ORG as alexander.kirwan@mycit.ie...
OK

Using route helloservletmaven.mybluemix.net
Binding helloservletmaven.mybluemix.net to /helloServletMaven...
OK

FAILED
Error processing app files: GetFileAttributesEx E:\helloServletMaven.war: The system cannot find the file specified.

E:\Program Files\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.41\webapps\helloServletMaven\target
λ ls
classes/  generated-sources/  helloServletMaven/  helloServletMaven.war  m2e-wtp/  maven-archiver/  maven-status/  test-classes/

E:\Program Files\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.41\webapps\helloServletMaven\target
```

But as you can see, when I run `ls`, I do have the war file.

Why is this happening?

By the way, I am using Windows and CMDER for the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your file is in the local directory so you don't have use `/helloServletMaven.war`, i.e. remove the slash (`/`)

`cf push helloServletMaven -p helloServletMaven.war`